# Receiving Cloud-to-Device messages from Azure to esp8266

Tags: azure, iot, arduino-esp8266

Using this project [here](https://github.com/gloveboxes/Arduino-ESP8266-Secure-Azure-IoT-Hub-Client) Im able to get an esp8266 to send messages to the Azure Iot hub, and I can read them with PowerBI. However, I would like to be able to use the device explorer Twin to send messages to the device.

I imagine that since the esp is sending messages to the Iot hub using an HTTP POST request, that I should be able to use an HTTP GET request to read the messages sent to the device when using the correct endpoint, outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging#cloud-to-device-messages).

Is this correct, or am I missing something? Doing this seems to only cause errors. If this is the right way, what would the format of a proper GET request be.

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you using HTTPS with the correct [request URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/receive-a-cloud-to-device-message) and the correct [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device-messaging-rest-apis#bk_common)? Have you [set the Authorization header to an appropriate SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#security-tokens)?

Comment: What does your GET request look like?

Comment: Here is the POST request I'm using. It successfully sends data to the IoT hub:


POST /devices/[Device ID]/messages/events?api-version=2016-02-03 HTTP/1.1
Host: [Device Group].azure-devices.net
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=[Shared Access Signature]
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 177

{"Dev":"[Device ID]","Utc":"2016-12-13T22:33:04","Celsius":60.00,"Humidity":30.00,"Setpoint":70,"State":0,"Geo":"West US","WiFi":0,"Mem":18728,"Id":2}

I've tried several variations on this to try and make a valid GET request but none have worked.

Comment: @ZacharyChristy Properly edit that into the question. It's unreadable inside comments,

Answer (score 0):

Receiving Cloud-to-Device message from Azure IoT hub via REST api you can use [GET method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/receive-a-cloud-to-device-message).

Different from POST method you need use "devicebound" instead of "events" in Request URI part.

About Common parameters and headers, only Authorization header is required and it is the same with in the POST request.

There is no body required in GET request.

So, your GET request would look like this:

```
GET /devices/[Device ID]/messages/devicebound?api-version=2016-02-03 HTTP/1.1 
Host: [IoTHubName].azure-devices.net 
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=[Shared Access Signature]
```